# iptables, redirect all port 80 to an IP but let one IP forwards through

Tags: linux, iptables

My router redirects all incoming traffic (interface *eth0*) to IP 1.2.3.4 :

```
iptables -t NAT -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 --to-destination 1.2.3.4:80
```

When a client hits "100.80.77.8", I'd like not to redirect him but let him access the www-online IP 100.80.77.8. (*Note: IP-Forwarding is ON*).

Finally any IP but 100.80.77.8 are catched and redirected to 1.2.3.4.

What iptables rules shall I add ? Before or after the redirect-all one (see above) ?

Thank you.

__ EDIT __ 
Here is the script I run to make my rules:

```
IPTABLES=iptables

# Enable Internet connection sharing,
echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

#clear all rules (flush)
$IPTABLES -F
$IPTABLES -X
$IPTABLES -t nat -F
$IPTABLES -t nat -X
$IPTABLES -t mangle -F
$IPTABLES -t mangle -X
$IPTABLES -P INPUT ACCEPT
$IPTABLES -P FORWARD ACCEPT
$IPTABLES -P OUTPUT ACCEPT

#rules--------

$IPTABLES -t nat -A PREROUTING -i wlan0  -d 100.80.77.8 -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT

#http (80)
$IPTABLES -t nat -A PREROUTING -i wlan0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 1.2.3.4
$IPTABLES -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE



echo "\nipforward: done. but Apple."
```

Comment: `iptables -t NAT -A PREROUTING -s 100.80.77.8 -p tcp --dport 80 --to-destination 100.80.77.8:80` I tried. Before all rules.

Comment: But that seems strange ... I m a noob in it. In addition, the requests are not made by IP but by domain name... So my problem should rather to dynamically add domain solving in dnsmasq... for instance `address=/patati/100.80.77.8`

Comment: Why `-s 100.80.77.8`? Shouldn't that be `-d 100.80.77.8`, since you want packets set TO that IP to be matched?

Comment: That should. Am a noob. What is -s for btw ?

Comment: Check the man page for iptables to find out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -d 100.80.77.8 -j ACCEPT
```

**before** the rule you show above (ie, handle the exception, *then* the rule).

`iptables` doesn't do DNS (in any way that you want) so abandon any thoughts of layer-4 handling - it's strictly a layer 2/3 tool.  If you find this doesn't work, we'll need to see **all** your rules to make any further comment, so edit the result of `iptables -L -n -v ; iptables -t nat -L -n -v` into your question.

Comment: thanks Mad, was reading a post of yours eleswhere ;) ""iptables doesn't do DNS (in any way that you want) "" Arfff... I m ttrying to dnsmasq the URL to 100.80.77.8. **I hope that URL--DNS-->100.80.77.8--iptables-->100.80.77.8**

Comment: Thanks Im on Mac, time to go on my Linux machine and I post that all... Done. Edit is made

Comment: Well it does not suit to my goal, thanks a lot anyway. The things work only if I bind domain and 100.80.77.8 in `dnsmasq`. I have bet on iptables cause you can add a rule dynamically. I just hope I can add an address in dnsmasq dynamically, compromised.